# IIS 7 working and I can see it on localmachine but not from anyother places

Tags: iis-7

I installed IIS7 on windows 2008r2 and it works like a charm and I can see it from the localhost but when I try to check it from other client there is no luck .
what should I do?

regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to know the error message the other client(s) get.

1. Check the firewall on the 2008r2 server and make sure HTTP isn't being blocked
2. Try browsing from the other clients by IP instead of machine name. Perhaps the issue is DNS name resolution